# How do I concat pages?

Tags: templates, haskell, pandoc, hakyll

I'm trying to automatically generate a bibliography in Hakyll. I'm using the `nocite` pandoc feature to generate a list of all publications in a .bib file. But, I'd like to have different sections (i.e. peer reviewed, theses, posters, etc.)

My idea on how to do this was to have a template like the following:

```
---
title: $title$
---
**Section: $title**
---
nocite: |
  @*
---
```

Then, I'd do the following:

- Use `pandocBiblioCompiler` to generate the page with the bibliography for each .bib file, applying the above template
- Concatenate them into one page
- Apply my main template (sidebar, navigation, etc.) to get the final page.

Is this possible? How do I concatenate multiple pages into one page in my `site.hs`?

Answer (score 1):

After some searching, it looks like the solution has two parts:

- Use `saveSnapshot` to record the results of `pandocBiblioCompiler` for each page
- Use `makeItem =<< applyTemplateList template context =<< loadAllSnapshots "pubs/*" "biblio"` to load the snapshots, concatenate them, and turn them into an `Item`